# Imagemagick replace color but keep transparency

Tags: imagemagick

I would like to replace all instances of black in a PNG logo with another color. I tried:

```
convert source.png -fill #123456 -opaque black out.png
```

But the logo has some transparent black pixels that are not converted. How can I change EVERY black pixel, but keep transparency on each?

Comment: did you manage to get the solution to your problem?

Comment: Try setting `-channel RGBA` near the start of the command, maybe?

Comment: I know it's been a while since this question was asked, but having a sample file would be very helpful to answer this question properly.

Answer (score 10):

```
convert in.png xc:"#ff0000" -channel RGB -clut  out.png
```

This will do the job. Provided that in.png has an alpha channel, the RGB channels in in.png will be replaced with red (#ff0000) while keeping the alpha channel untouched.

What happens here?
in.png is the first input image. xc:"#ff0000" is the second input image (the xc: special file is interpreted by ImageMagick as an image all filled with the given color). The -clut option ("Color Look  Up Table") interprets the second image as a lookup table and applies it to the values in the first image. Since the second image is monochrome, every color in the first is mapped to red in this  example. The last file name (out.png) is interpreted as the output file.

Why does -clut not affect the alpha channel?
Well, you can set the affected channels with the -channel option. It must go before the -clut. RGB is what we want here.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
convert source.png -channel RGB -fuzz 99% -fill blue -opaque black dest.png
```

But it will work only if your logo was monochrome (like iOS icons - only one color and transparency).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I have spent an unbelievably long time, and found no answer. But at last I figured it out.

**NOTE:** My image is an all-black, making it grayscale with alpha. (i.e. all my pixels look like: R=0, G=0, B=0, A=X . Your pixels can be anything else, I think you will be able to adjust my answer.

```
convert in_file.png -alpha off -fuzz 100% -fill blue -opaque '#000000' -alpha on -format png32 out_file.png32
```

**What's happening here?**

1. `alpha off` this means, if the image had no alpha channel, then
   nothing changes, if your image did have an alpha channel, subsequent
   operations will pretend it is not there.
2. Unfortunately, when saving the image with `.png` postfix, imagemagick will decide to use the most efficient format, indexed. I have no idea, why, but it thinks my image is 1 bit representable: full transparency/full opaque color, and I loose all the finer details of the alpha channel. Maybe there are other solutions for this, but my surefire way was using the '.png32' postfix on the filename. This means, the image must be saved in 8bit-8bit-8bit-8bit RGBA format.

**Anyway, if you try to debug, why your image pipeline does not work with transparency:**

- open the image with gimp
- at the top bar of the window you should see either `...Indexed color...`, or something else, like `...RGB color...`. If you see `Indexed color`, maybe your pipeline is already working well, only it saves in the wrong format!

Yeah, this is a double error... You may have already got it right dozens of times regarding 1 of the errors... Guess what I was thinking when I found this out after hours of hopeless googling and trying....

*Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-31 http://www.imagemagick.org*

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick if you have tranparency, then try

```
convert source.png -alpha off -fuzz XX% -fill "#123456" -opaque black -alpha on out.png
```

where XX is some percent close to black that you may want to include. If you only want to change pure black then you can set XX=0.

Note that the above code will change all black pixels to the new color, including any black color under the transparency.

If you only want to change fully opaque black to the new color and not any black under the transparency, then include alpha values in your colors. So try

```
convert source.png  -fuzz XX% -fill "#123456FF" -opaque "graya(0)" -alpha on out.png
```

If using IM 7, then change convert to magick.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, the previous replies have a drawback to my opinion: if your drawing has soft edges (thanks to the alpha channel), you lose them and your result has only sharp edges.
With this command the soft edges are preserved:

```
magick in_file.png -fill "#6696DC" -colorize 100% out_file.png32
```

As mentioned by Zoltan, I need to use the png32 suffix to enforce png 32 bits encoding. Then, just need to rename the file after its generation (removing the 32) and you got the working file with the right extension.

Note: I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.8-24 Q16 x64.

Comment: In Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert and not convert. Using -colorize is going to colorize the whole image with that color. That does not seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood but the originial question is talking about "all instances of black in a PNG logo with another color". And other replies also considered the target is a monochrome picture, grayscaled with alpha. Anyway, you are right the colorize command is monochrom. And yes, I corrected the IM7 command removing convert. Thank you.